# metric space continuity limit

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits

Here I am given the definition for a continuous function on a metric space.

> Def:
>
> Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,e)$ be metric spaces.
>
> Let $f:(X,d)\rightarrow (Y,e)$
>   be a function and let $a \in X$.
>
> $f$ is called continuous if for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ s.t $f(B_\delta(a)) \subseteq B_\epsilon (f(a))$

An example supplied is this:
[image]

From the example, it seems that the open ball $B_\delta(a)$
is given to be $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$

What did that ordered pairs came from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which ordered pairs do you mean? If you mean $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$, it is not an ordered pair. It is an open interval.

Comment: Also it should be "$f$ is continuous *at a* if ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ordered pair" is not actually an ordered pair. It is supposed to denote the open interval $(a - \delta, a + \delta)$.

Maybe it could be written more clearly as $f((a-\delta,a+\delta))$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. 
A related point: I do not yet quite understand why the open ball is the open interval as it is. Would you explain?

Comment: @Mathematicing: $(a - \delta, a + \delta)$ is just $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a - \delta < x < a + \delta$.

Comment: Helpful. Thanks.